# Form Post method passing only null and 0 to other page

Tags: php, forms, post, input, mysqli

I need to pass values from a cell inside my main page to another page.

I have to pass: `Monday` `9.00` `Username` `week` `year`. Last 3 defined inside an input returned `NULL` in my database. First 2 returned `0`. All those values should be known in the main page so the user doesn't have to insert anything.

Username is even printed before in the main page. Input requires some sort of action from the user? If so (which could explain the `null` and `0` values) how can I pass values without having to make the user insert something?

Here's the code and some screen describing my situation.

```
// First cell form to pass data to booking.php
 <?php
   $week = date("W");
   $year = (isset($_GET['year']))?$_GET['year']:date("Y");
   $week = (isset($_GET['week']))?$_GET['week']:Date('W');
   if($week>52){
     $year+= 1;
     $week=1;
    }elseif($week < 1) {
        $year--;
        $week = 52;
    }
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a> <!--Settimana Precendete-->
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next  Week</a> <!--Settimana Prossima-->
 <table border="1px" class="WeekLayout">
 <tr>
 <td>Schedule</td>
<?php
if($week < 10) {
$week = '0'. $week;
}

 for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
 {
    $d = strtotime($year."W".$week.$day);                           
    echo "<td>".date('l',$d )."<br>";
    echo date('d M Y',$d)."</td>";
 }
 ?>
 </tr>

 <form action="Booking.php" method="POST" name="BookingForm" id="BookingForm">
 <tr class="9">
 <td>9.00
 </td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href="">              </a>
    <input type="hidden" name="Monday">
    <input type="hidden" name="9.00"></td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href=""></a></td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href=""></a></td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href=""></a></td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href=""></a></td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href=""></a></td>
 <td class="free" onclick="Change(this)"><a href=""></a></td>   
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </table>
 <input type="hidden" name="$Username">
 <input type="hidden" name="$week">
 <input type="hidden" name="$year">
 <input value="Prenota" type="submit" class="buttonsubmit" id="Prenota">
 </form>
 </div>
//Connection to database
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'elencoprenotazioni';
$host = 'localhost';
$dblink2 = new mysqli($host,  $user,  $password, $db)
or die("Connessione non riuscita: " . mysqli_error());
?>
//Prenotation system
<?php
include("Connessione2.php");
session_start();
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$week = $_POST['week'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$queryinsert = mysqli_query($dblink2, "INSERT INTO calendario                         (Username, week, year, day, hour) VALUES  ('$Username','$week','$year','$day','$hour')");
if($queryinsert)
{
header("location: index.html");
}
mysqli_close();
?>
```

Doing this way inside my database I only got this:

[image: pic1]

As you can see I get `0` for values that should be in my main page and `null` from values I define inside my form.

Full view of the page:

[image: pic2]

As you can see from URL `week` and `year` should be known and `Username` is printed just near the logout button.

Comment: I was going to try to fix your HTML indents, and realized you have all sorts of tags messed up. For example, you close the table before the form end, but didn't open the table after the form start. You should start with fixing your HTML and using proper indentation.

Comment: Forgot to copy here a part of the code(the ones related to the first row of the table). Unfortunately indents is the only part working fine

Comment: You have a *lot* of errors — https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: @Quentin checked and solved all cases. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using values in name attribute?

Please change these...

```
<input type="hidden" name="Monday">
<input type="hidden" name="9.00"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="$Username">
<input type="hidden" name="$week">
<input type="hidden" name="$year">
```

to these first

```
<input type="hidden" name="day" value="Monday">
<input type="hidden" name="hour" value="9.00"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="Username" name="MyUsername">
<input type="hidden" name="week" name="53">
<input type="hidden" name="year" name="2016">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Ok with values i can insert datas in my database but 1) you mean name="week" value="53" right? 2) username week and year can change going from week 53 to week 1 and year 2017. how can i make this adaptive?  thought that since those values are stored in my year and week variables i could use those